# Solve : In a right angled ∆ the hypotenuse is 4 times as long as perpendicular drawn to it from opposite vertex .Its acute angles are

Tags: trigonometry

My try : [image]

c2 = h2 + (a-x)2
b2 = h2 + x2
on adding, we have  2h2 + x2 + (a-x)2 = a2 ..(1)
also a = 4h  and cos B = b/a = x/b
so x = b2/a
on solving (1), we have  h2 + x2 -4hx = 0
substituting above gives
b4 + a4/16 -a2.b2 =0 .. (2)
as cos B = b/a
on solving eqn. (2) we have ,  Cos2B = 0.933 or 0.067
B = 15 or 75 degrees
as B is acute , B is 15 degrees
I want one more solution different from it.

Comment: Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site, then edit your question to improve its legibility.

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

Draw the base $AB$ and then a (Thales) semicircle with diameter $AB$. Find the locus of all points $C$ with height ${|AB|\over4}$ over the base. Stare at the resulting figure. In the end no computing is necessary.

[image]

Comment: Sorry , Christian but I don't know anything about Thales semicircle

Answer (score 0):

[image]

\begin{align} 
|CH|=|C'H|&=\tfrac14|AB|=\tfrac12R
,\\
|CC'|&=|OC|=|OC'|=R
,\\
\text{hence, }\quad 
\angle C'OC&=60^\circ
,\\
\angle C'BC&=\tfrac12 \angle C'OC
=30^\circ
,\\
\angle ABC&=
\beta=\tfrac12 \angle C'BC
=15^\circ
,\\
\angle CAB&=
\alpha=90^\circ-\beta
=75^\circ
.
\end{align}